# Retrieving resource id from string value

Tags: android

I know how to retrieve a resID from the name of the string which is present in strings.xml

```
        <string name="text">Chennai</string>
```

We can retrieve the resID by following

```
          int id = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier("text","string", this.context.getPackageName());
```

How can retrieve the id by using the value **Chennai** is it possible to do or its impossible 
any help is appreciated

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I have to set the values for the variables of a class according to the key obtained if its a switch statement then it will be easier

Comment: What happens if you have 5 different strings defined with the same text? Which id should it return? :) AFAIK it's not a unique mapping.

Comment: I am sure that it would be a different strings if its string A i will set a value for A if B i will set a value for B so i have nearly 10 like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible as the string values are not required to be unique. Therefore you can't get "the id" back as potentially you could have multiple ids mapping to the same string.

For example:

```
<string name="text">Chennai</string>
<string name="text2">Chennai</string>
<string name="text3">Chennai</string>
```

is completely acceptable. How can you get "the id" back for the string "Chennai"?

Comment: you are correct i have to try something out of this thank you

Answer (score -2):

try this in your code - R.string.text