# get string Id by string content

Tags: android, string, identifier

I know I can search for a string identifier in my R.java by:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("homestring", "string", getPackageName());
```

But my problem is that string homestring has a value and I only know that value and need the resource name and identifier.

```
<string name="homestring">String value</string>
```

I only know "String value" and want to get "homestring" as a result.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: why do you need this? if you describe the scenaio then may be an alternative solution can be found

Comment: It's not possible because the content is not unique. You could have multiple ids defining the same string. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934569/retrieving-resource-id-from-string-value/16934753#16934753